# Ionic 4 : How to change small icon in Onesignal

Tags: ionic-framework, notifications, ionic4, onesignal

How to change small icon image in one signal notifications ?

I have used my app icon image in Android Asset Studio to create notification icons. But it is showing grey box in notification.

When I tried white and transparent image it is working but I need colored image in notification small icon. Is there any way using that I can create colored small image?

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: If you have other device please check in that. Might be it's depends on os version.